# App crashing in iPhone 4s and 5s only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app is crashing in iPhone 4S and iPhone 5S only, works fine in all other devices and simulators. 
[image: Stack and log information]

I have checked for IBOutlet connection issues also checked for keyPath values in User Defined Run time attributes section of the concerned view..

EDIT:
I put breakpoint in ViewDidLoad () and ViewWillAppear () even that is not getting called. App crashes before that..

Comment: see the console report u r added the missed key

Comment: just check if u set the controllers of all the views correctly in storyboard in the identity inspector

Comment: Why does it says @"idleTimeCheck"? I've never seen anyone change that part before

Comment: @VamshiKrishna I am not using Storyboard. I have checked all Xib connections are proper.

Comment: @kylecman That is noway connected to this issue. We are subclassing Appdelegate with that..

Comment: try to  reset the simulator .. clean your solution once.rebuild ..run

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik could not understand..

Comment: @VamshiKrishna In simulator its working fine.. still do you think I need to do that..

Comment: @ibiren - ref this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Comment: @ibiren my bad just curious. try to "clean the project" is what Vamshi is saying. Use command+shift+k. And i'd would try to use an exceptional break point.

Comment: Can you put "Add Exception Breakpoint" and see at what line it throws an exception? I suspect you are using some member not available on older iOS versions from UIView.

Answer (score 1):

Error Log clearly saying that you have problem with key-value for any class. Please check again. Or if you are storing anything in user default and update your code then you should first remove previous install app.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `xib` or `storyboard` in xcode, select `File's Owner` and click on the `Connection Inspector` (upper right arrow), to see all outlets at once.
Look for `!`s which indicates a missing outlet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have a proper IBOutlet connnection to one of your viewController. Just go through with all the viewController connections in your xib files. Better unlink and link them again this might can solve the issue as every connection will be checked and connected again.

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard/xib corresponding to the viewcontroller/views in there. For each item, check the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" in the "Identity Inspector" (3rd tab on right pane) and check whether an attribute with "keypath" is created there.